# Replace spaces in a matched substring with underscores

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm new to the forum so please forgive any syntactical errors in my question.

I'm trying to replace spaces with underscores in a matched substring only. I figured sed would be the best editor for this but I cannot find the proper code to do this.

Sample line from file1 below:

> Some text before pattern to match href="./**Dynamic Directory name -
>   Junk_files**/irrelevant stuff after match">

Would like to change to this:

> Some text before pattern to match
>   href="./**Dynamic_Directory_name_-_Junk_files**/irrelevant stuff after
>   match">

I thought I was close with this `cat file1 |sed '/\.\/.*. Junk_files/ { s/ /_/g; }'` but all it did was replace all spaces on the matched line with underscores.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You're asking for a `sed` solution, but you're clearly unsatisfied with the answers. That's because `sed` (and other text-processing tools) are extremely limited when it comes to parsing HTML. You might want to add more examples, remove the `sed` tag and ask for a solution which won't necessarily have to involve `sed` or other text-processing tools.

Comment: Is  this for text in a file or would you actually like to do this for filenames? There is an easy way to do this for all the filenames in a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through python,

```
$ echo 'href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match"' |
> python -c "import re;
> import sys;
> print re.sub(r'(?<=\./).*?(?=/)', lambda m: m.group().replace(' ', '_'), sys.stdin.read())
> "
href="./Dynamic_Directory_name_-_Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match"
```

Through perl,

```
$ echo 'href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/irrelevant stuff' | perl -pe '
> s/\s(?=(?:(?!\.\/).)*?\/)/_/g
> '
href="./Dynamic_Directory_name_-_Junk_files/irrelevant stuff
```

Comment: They both seem to be working, so +1. However *most likely* the full line is `Some text before pattern to match href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match">` (by the way the commands are just not copy-pastable, you might want to fix that).

Comment: Getting unwanted results with the perl code, but the python seems to be working correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this, it finds the first pair of slashes and removes all spaces between!**

```bash
 awk -F'/' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if(i==2)gsub(" ","_",$i);}1' OFS="/"
```

**Example**

```bash
file='href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match">' 
echo $file | awk -F'/' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if(i==2)gsub(" ","_",$i);}1' OFS="/"
# Output: 
href="./Dynamic_Directory_name_-_Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match">
```

Comment: This example replaces every space in the file with underscores. I need only the spaces in the folder name to be replaced with underscores.

Comment: ok I edit it, this works now!

Comment: Well maybe there is still a prob. how long is your url? How many subdirectories do you have?

Comment: Okay now it works also with subdirs. I had to schange `i%2==0` to `i==2`!

Comment: Pls accept it as correct answer if it works for you. If there is a better answer coming you can always change your choice.

Comment: This works if there are no preceding "/" on the matched line. This will not work for lines such as **bold**<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/commonPrint.css">**bold**.

Comment: Wiht `sed -r 's/^.+href="([^"]+)".+$/\1/'` you can select the value of `href=""`

Comment: Sorry still getting unwanted results with `awk -F'/' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if(i==2)gsub(" ","_",$i);}1' OFS="/"`. For example this line **<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/commonPrint.css">** would return **<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"_media="print"_href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/commonPrint.css">**.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use an XML parser.

If you insist on using `sed`; assuming the pattern stays consistent:

```
sed -r 's#^([^/]+/[^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) - ([^ ]+/)#\1_\2_\3_-_\4#' file.txt
```

This will replace all spaces between two forward slashes (`/`) with underscores (`_`). As the input contains `/`, i have used `#` as the pattern separator for `sed`.

**Example:**

```
% sed -r 's#^([^/]+/[^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) - ([^ ]+/)#\1_\2_\3_-_\4#' <<<'Some text before pattern to match href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match">'
Some text before pattern to match href="./Dynamic_Directory_name_-_Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match">
```

Comment: This only adds underscores before and after the dash in the folder name. I need all spaces in the folder name to be replaced with underscores. The consistent pattern would be href"./Folder name with spaces - Junk_files/.

Comment: @kos Thanks..did not notice..edited..

Comment: @dparz Check my edit

Comment: Doesn't work if the folder name longer. eg. `file='href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files is sometimes longer/irrelevant stuff after match/test test/">'`. See my example it works: http://askubuntu.com/a/741165/189996

Comment: This works but is limited to a static count of spaces. The folder names in the files I need to edit can vary in the amount of spaces that are in them. Your code works on the original example provided, but does not work on either of these: [Here is another href="./Here is a very long folder name to test - Junk_files/blahblah.css"] or [Smaller folder href="./Cat - Junk_files/].

Comment: @dparz check http://askubuntu.com/a/741165/189996

Answer (score 0):

That's HTML, and unless you have a very well defined a simple enough subset of HTML in your file, parsing HTML using regular expressions is a pretty bad idea.

This Perl one-liner works for replacing that substring in that specific context:

```
printf 'Some text before pattern to match href="./Dynamic Directory name - Junk_files/irrelevant stuff after match">\n' | perl -ne 'if(/(.*?")(.*\/)(.*)/){$x = $1; $y = $2; $z = $3; $y =~ s/ /_/g; print("$x$y$z")}'
```

Meaning: it will just replace spaces with underscores in the first `"` and `/` delimited substring found. But that's about it. If you're parsing a complex document, **don't use it**. You could make the pattern more strict (for example you could use `/href=(.*?")(.*\/)(.*)/` and `print("href=$x$y$z")`), but that could still fail upon any occurrence of `/href=(.*?")(.*\/)(.*)/`.

Unless you're parsing a very well defined and simple enough subset of HTML in your file and you're *sure* something like that won't fail, just use an HTML parser.